# iPhone connection error with Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I want to test my application on real device for the first time, but when I try to connect the iPhone to xcode I get shown an error message :

> (The device is passcode protected.Please unlock your device and reattach, (0xE800001A)).

Please can anyone help me I have done a lot of search on it but unfortunately I couldn't find the any solution.

Comment: Unlock your device then use it for running your app.

Comment: Did you *try* what Xcode suggests in the error message?

Comment: Pretty damn obvious what is wrong. Your iPhone is protected by a pin (The lock screen) you need to unlock the phone so it goes to the home screen where the apps appear. simple as. Voted to close as **Demonstrates a minimal understanding** -1 as well

Answer (score 6):

The error message clearly states you solution: **`The device is passcode protected.Please unlock your device and reattach`**

You have pass code set to unlock you phone, which also adds some protection and restricts access to your device. Unlock you device before connecting it will allow Xcode to acces your device.

Comment: thanks RCKOENES please can you explain me how can i unlock device.

Comment: @Bilalhussain: it is your phone?you should know passcode

Comment: You slide your finger over the `Slide to unlock` message of your iPhone. Then it will ask for you passcode and after you entered it you phone will be unlocked.

Comment: sir I do the same process that you say Slide to unloke and also set the passcode but same problem is ocurring

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using and what is the version of iOS on the device.

Comment: preetam I know its my Phone and I also Know Passcode but when i connect it with Mac then its not show the device in orgnizer and not in Xcode. I am suffering in this problem last 5 hour. But Can't success found.

Comment: I m usign Xcode 4.6 and device OS version is ios 7.

Comment: You will need Xcode 5 for device with iOS 7. Once the device is activated on Xcode 5 on your machine you can use Xcode 4 for development.

Comment: rckoenes no its not solution

Comment: @Bilalhussain Have you provisioned the device? Are you even registered as an Apple Developer? These are very simple things that as a developer you should know. And if you don't even know how to unlock the phone you are definitely going to struggle.

Comment: Same here but no fix found.

Comment: I've just had the same issue (and the phone WAS unlocked). I just disconnected the lightning cable and connected again and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is obvious by the error that you are getting that your iPhone is protected by a pin (The lock screen).

Steps :

> 1. Swipe finger across screen
> 2. Enter pin code
> 3. You should now be on the iPhone home screen (where the apps appear)

If it still doesn't show up in xcode there could be a range of different issues.

> - Device isn't provisioned (Requires an Apple Developer account, paid account not free)
> - You are running an xcode below xcode 5 and running iOS 7, iOS 7 requires xcode 5 minimum.

If you're not registered as an Apple Developer (paid account, not free) then you will not be able to run your app on a device. To run an App on a device you are required to provision the device that you are using which will make it so you can use it for development and testing purposes.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to `rckoenes` comments - if you have both `xcode 5` and `xcode 4` installed on the same machine, then after connecting an iOS7 device in `xcode 5` you can use it in both `xcode 5` and `xcode 4` until the device is reset.